# Perl dependancy problems installing Webmin

Tags: server, software-installation, perl, webmin, cpan

I just installed webmin from a .deb file. on Ubuntu Server 12.04, which went ok.

I logged in at the web interface and checked the "Perl Modules" page. There was on module suggested but not installed. I selected it and pressed install and got the following error:

```
Making, testing and installing Authen::Libwrap ..

Untarring module file

Executing gunzip -c /tmp/.webmin/Authen-Libwrap-0.22.tar.gz | tar xvf - ..

Authen-Libwrap-0.22
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/Build.PL
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/ChangeLog
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/example.pl
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/Makefile.PL
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/MANIFEST
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/META.yml
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/ppport.h
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/README
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/lib
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/lib/Authen
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/lib/Authen/Libwrap.pm
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/lib/Authen/Libwrap.xs
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/t
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/t/01_inline.t
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/t/02_maintainer.t
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/t/03_pod.t
Authen-Libwrap-0.22/t/hosts.allow

Compiling module

Executing /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL  && make ..

# running Build.PL 
enter include directory to use: [/usr/include ]/usr/include 
enter library directory to use: [/usr/lib ]/usr/lib 
Warning: ExtUtils::CBuilder not installed or no compiler detected
Proceeding with configuration, but compilation may fail during Build

Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Authen-Libwrap' version '0.22'
/usr/bin/perl Build --makefile_env_macros 1
Building Authen-Libwrap
Error: Function definition too short '/ * EOF * /' in Libwrap.xs, line 32
Error: no compiler detected to compile 'lib/Authen/Libwrap.c'.  Aborting
make: *** [all] Error 255

Installation of Authen::Libwrap failed. Check the output above and try installing manually.
You can also install the module from CPAN with the command perl -MCPAN -e shell.
```

I've installed `ExtUtils::CBuilder` successfully I think from the cpan command line but still I get the same error when installing 'Authen-LibWrap'.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu will need these installed to work:

```
sudo apt-get install libwrap0 libwrap0-dev
```

Comment: `Error: no compiler detected to compile ...` indicates that even gcc is not installed.